# Button clicked navigates to social media page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Hello I'm trying to implement a button in Xamarin forms and once the button is clicked it would take the user to a social media page. I'm not exactly sure how to implement that can someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not exist to write your code for you.

Comment: Make a hyperlink, and set a social media logo as the link text.

Comment: @IanKemp thanks for the feedback. Ill keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

in your xaml

```
<Button text="Click Me" Clicked="LaunchSite" />
```

in your code behind using [Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher)

```
protected async void LaunchSite(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Launcher.OpenAsync("http://facebook.com");
}
```